# Monitor two Java processes on the same machine using Zabbix

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx, zabbix

I have a machine with two running Java processes. Each of them can be monitored on a unique ports using JMX. E.g port 10001 and 10002.

I would like to use Zabbix 2.0 to monitor the memory usage of each Java process. However I am struggling with making it work which probably has something to with me being quite new to Zabbix.

In Zabbix I have added two JMX interfaces to the host running the two Java processes. One uses port 10001 and the other one uses port 10002.

I have created one JMX item for the first JXM interface (10001) using the key `jmx["java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage.used"]`. It is working quite fine.

When trying to create the second JMX item for the second JMX interface (10002) using the same key I get the following error:

> Item with key "jmx["java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage.used"]" already exists on "Zabbix server".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, keys must be unique in all cases.

Usually this is handled by adding an argument to a key, for instance a port number to the key.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment made me come up with a hack that seems to work: whitespace. By inserting an extra space just before "]" the key becomes unique.

However I believe that this cannot/should not be the solution.